# How to declare types for empty object array with typescript?

Tags: typescript

Say the array is `const items = [{category:'cat1', name:'name1'},{category:'cat2', name:'name2'}]`.

I want to construct the above array to become an object format like the following:

```
{
  'cat1':'name1',
  'cat2':'name2'
}
```

Without typescript, I can do the following to solve the problem:

```
const parseFunction = (items) => {
 const newObj = {};
 for (const item of items) {
   newObj[item.category] = newObj[item.name];
 }
 return newObj;
}
```

However with typescript below:

```
interface IItems{
 category: string,
 name: string
}

interface INewObj{
 'cat1': string,
 'cat2': string
}

const parseFunction = (items: IItems[]) => {
 const newObj = {} as INewObj;
 for (const item of items) {
   newObj[item.category] = newObj[item.name];
 }
 return newObj;
}
```

The line `newObj[item.category] = newObj[item.name]` throws the following TS error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type 'IQuotaByCategory'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'IQuotaByCategory'.ts(7053)
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Does this solution can suit your needs?

Use [Record<Keys, Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to map the unknown keys and values.

**Typescript code**

```js
const items: IItems[] = [{ category: 'cat1', name: 'name1' }, { category: 'cat2', name: 'name2' }];

interface IItems {
    category: string,
    name: string
}

type NewObjType = Record<string, string>;

const parseFunction = (items: IItems[]): NewObj => {
    const newObj: NewObjType = {};

    for (const item of items) {
        newObj[item.category] = item.name;
    }

    return newObj;
}

console.log(parseFunction(items));
```

**Javascript Snippet**

```js
"use strict";
const items = [{ category: 'cat1', name: 'name1' }, { category: 'cat2', name: 'name2' }];
const parseFunction = (items) => {
    const newObj = {};
    for (const item of items) {
        newObj[item.category] = item.name;
    }
    return newObj;
};
console.log(parseFunction(items));
```

PS: You made a little mistake here `newObj[item.category] = newObj[item.name]` since the value does not already exists in the newObj variable. I have changed to the correct assignment as follow: `newObj[item.category] = item.name`

Answer (score 1):

In practice I'm guessing you wouldn't really know that the categories were `cat1`, `cat2` etc, all you'd know is that they would be strings. Therefore the definition of `INewObj` needs to be a little more permissive.

```
type INewObj = {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

Which can be further shortened to `Record<string, string>`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKsgWwM7IN4BQyyCckA5gPZQCeAXMtmFKOUciHJhA0yyGwC%20BAmBoAHFKgByEAO4B5AEYArZAF587ANoBrCPUbNWAXV7GBBYQQSUQTZOLhRsEAGIBXEAjDA7G5AAKYCxsBnRQ7RMASg0APi1iW3swDnllFXDZRVUAvGFiGGog5IcQiExkShhkcpxYwmJiEHTVbTqAOlIKahoTAJaclXasDs5uE3ZrYigIMA8oEDShqwIgA)

You could go further and eliminate `INewObj` entirely by allowing Typescript to infer it for you:

[Playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKsgWwM7IN4BQyyCckA5gPZQCeAXMtmFKOUciHJhA0yyGwC%20BAgkogmyAA5wo2CADEAriARhg45AF5kACmBZsDdIYDaAXQCU2gHzsDEHADooEACZKkAHgBKEMVBuXnysADSMzKw2NrrsxLqICOHA1lo2eoTEWchOuYmhcVmmwE6kFNQ05gwlnNyFgpYF2XjCxJYEQA)